# Throwing InvalidCastException on extracting a column max value from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have 3 columns in my SQL Server database i.e `sr_no int`, `user_id nvarchar(50)`, `name nvarchar(50)`

When I run the code below it gives me `InvalidCastException` whereas where I find the max from `sr_no` or name it gives me the correct value.

So far the values stored in the `user_id` are all numerical.

C# code:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    var id = (from a in context.User_profiles select a.user_id).Max();

    _id.Text = "USR-" + id.ToString();    
}
```

Comment: If `user_id` is a `String`, why do you want to use `Max`? Make it an `int` column. Otherwise `"2"` is "greater" than `"10"`.

Comment: actually i am creating a proper strategy for id e.g USR-1, thats why i have kept it nvarchar.

Comment: If that is _your_ data(not imported from an external system) don't store `USR-1` but only `1`. The `USR-` can be prepended where you need to diplay it.

Comment: i did not get you point..please elaborate

Comment: so far the data is not stored in the USR-1 format...the data is integers so far in format of nvarchar

Comment: but when i use max with name it give me the right name with max

Comment: Invalid cast from what Type to what Type? Where's your C# mapping file entries for this table?

Comment: from nvarchar to int

Answer (score 0):

Since *"data is integers so far in format of nvarchar"* and  `Max` wont work for strings all the times, try doing like this,

```
    using (DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        var id = (from obj in context.User_profiles
                  let num = context.User_profiles.Select(x => x.user_id).Cast<int>().Max()
                  select num).FirstOrDefault();

        _id.Text = "USR-" + id.ToString();
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: still the same exeception

Comment: A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Comment: after .select( when 'x' appears, it is underlined red.

Comment: same again...throwing the same exception "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: Can you try putting breakpoint and check at which "x.user_id" does it throw the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66641/discussion-between-vanest-and-haider-khattak).